# How can i loop through all ids starting with chart in the element?

Tags: jquery, loops, find

I am using jquery to find a div with a specific class name.

```
$founddiv = $this.find(".more-info");
```

Now I want to loop through all divs in $founddiv starting the id with "chart...".

This is the structure of the site:

```
<div class="more-info">
   <div class="text"></div>
   <div id="chart1"></div>
   <div class="text"></div>
   <div id="chart2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+id+start+with